# Hacer un concatenate con los resultados de un loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un pequeño dataframe en un loop, y quiero concatenar todas las salidas posibles del loop. Imaginense:

Tengo df1, df2, que contienen valores de a y b. filtro con el loop que en ambos solo tenga el trozo de dataframe con los valores a y b en sus listas. Aplico alpha. Obtengo un resultado (dfresultado). Lo que quiero es concatenar los multiples dfresultado que me de cada loop, pero no tengo un dfresultado_0

tengo una lista de indices, un dataframe vacio:

```
list = ['oct', 'nov', 'dic']

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'nick'], 'marks_1':[99, 98, 95], 'marks_2':[99, 98, 95]} 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['oct', 'nov', 'dic']) 
data2 = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'nick'], 'marks_3':[99, 98, 95], 'marks_4':[99, 98, 95]} 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index =['oct', 'nov', 'dic']) 
dfresultado_0 = pd.DataFrame(index=list)
```

Y ahora dentro de un loop q va recrriendo valores, quiero concatenar los resultados sumando la primera columna. Es decir, el sistema hará una primera iteracion, en la que dfresultado se concatenará con dfresultado_0 (como está vacio, es como sumar un 0. Antes de eso, el dfresultado q obtengo en cada iteracion, tendrá n columnas, la primera columna [0], que se sume al valor de la primera columna de dfresultado_0 (como es un cero, no pasa mas), pero en las siguientes iteraciones la primera columna de esos 3 meses no será cero

```
for a in list1:
    for b in list2:
        dfresultado = alpha(df1,df2)
        # obtengo la primera columna del dfresultado y la sumo a la primera columna de dfresultado_0
        #concateno el resto de columnas que tenga al dfresultado_0
        dfresultado_0 = np.concatenate((dfresultado_0, dfresultado), axis=1)


dfresultado será del tipo:
oct    90    80    70
nov    80    80    60 
dic    70    50    50
en cada iteracion (con mas o menos columnas)

y querría un resultado del tipo:
oct    190    80    70   40    40  50   70
nov    130    80    60   30    30  60   50
dic    150    50    50   30    20  60   70
con la primera columna la suma en las difrentes iteraciones, y concatenadas las columnas de notas (la primera de cada iteracion desaparece)
```

Comment: No se entiende bien sin un ejemplo más concreto, pero quizás todo lo que necesites sea inicializar con algo como `df = pd.DataFrame()`  un datagrama vacío al que ir concatenando las cosas. El ejemplo que planteas tiene varias cosas muy poco claras, como por ejemplo de dónde salen `df1` y `df2`, por qué usas `np` en lugar de `pd`, por qué reasignas `dfresultado` en cada iteración del bucle (con lo que perderías lo que le hubieras concatenado en iteraciones previas), etc. Intenta poner un ejemplo que, aunque sea mínimo, tenga al menos algunos datos con que probar y sea "casi" ejecutable.

Comment: modificado, espero que asi valga, no puedo desvelar lo que hace la funcion alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de unir los resultados de varios loops en una linea de codigo es la siguiente:

```
jugadores = ['Martha', 'Juan', 'Carla']
pocisiones = [1, 2, 3]

posibles_resultados = [(p, j) for p in pocisiones for j in jugadores]

print(f'Existen {len(posibles_resultados)} posibles resultado') # Existen 9 posibles resultado
print(f'Todos los posibles resultado son estos {posibles_resultados}') # Todos los posibles resultado son estos [(1, 'Martha'), (1, 'Juan'), (1, 'Carla'), (2, 'Martha'),..
```

Espero te sirva un saludo :)